# How to setup Firebase distribution in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-android

I'm trying to add firebase distribution to my flutter app following [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#console)

Everything is file until I get to step 3.b which says "In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually //build.gradle), add the Google services plugin".

I can't figure out what "app-module" refers to or where the path to the gradle file is. If I append it to the /android/app/build.gradle the build crashes. Can somebody please tell me exactly which file and where to paste this content? There is no similar pattern for plugins anywhere.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Just Like this in buid.gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your /android/build.gradle begins like this:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
// More code...
```

It is using buildscript syntax, in that case, add the plugin like this:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
  }
}
// More code...
```

Assuming Firebase instruction for /android/build.gradle is to add:

```
plugins {
  // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}
```

**Sources:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#groovy

(The part where it says: "Are you still using the buildscript syntax? Learn how to add Firebase plugins using that syntax")